# Pandas groupby() different output with versions 0.23.4 and 1.3.4

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have 2 codebases with the same code, the only difference is the version of pandas being used:

- OLD environment uses pandas version 0.23.4
- NEW environment uses pandas version 1.3.4

I have debugged my code up to this line of code, after which the `result` is different:

`result = df.groupby(group_items, as_index=as_index, sort=sort)[sum_items].sum()`

Variables `df`, `group_items`, `as_index`, `sort` and `sum_items` are all exactly the same between both NEW and OLD environments.

However, the returned `result` is a little bit different in the NEW version. Specifically, the output looks like this:

NEW environment:

```
df.groupby(group_items, as_index=as_index, sort=sort)[sum_items].sum()
        SST_ADJ_TYPE    SST_ADJ_RULE  ... NCI     AMOUNT
0                  0  SST22a,SST22b,  ...      1874757.0
1                  0  SST22a,SST22b,  ...      5945263.0
2                  0  SST22a,SST22b,  ...      4303110.0
3                  0  SST22a,SST22b,  ...      5342991.0
4                  0  SST22a,SST22b,  ...      9245478.0
...              ...             ...  ...  ..        ...
133674             3   SST22b,SST07,  ...      4164305.0
133675             3   SST22b,SST07,  ...      7280203.0
133676             3   SST22b,SST07,  ...      1235752.0
133677             3   SST22b,SST07,  ...      3115825.0
133678             3   SST22b,SST07,  ...      1436891.0
[133679 rows x 16 columns]
```

OLD environment:

```
df.groupby(group_items, as_index=as_index, sort=sort)[sum_items].sum()
        SST_ADJ_TYPE    SST_ADJ_RULE    ...     NCI     AMOUNT
0                  0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          1874757.0
1                  0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          5945263.0
2                  0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          4303110.0
3                  0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          5342991.0
4                  0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          9245478.0
5                  0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          4016202.0
6                  0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          8799969.0
7                  0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          1503269.0
8                  0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          6385991.0
9                  0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          1686520.0
10                 0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          5287114.0
11                 0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          2648534.0
12                 0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          6159017.0
13                 0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          5959591.0
14                 0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          5809998.0
15                 0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          4929077.0
16                 0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          9166004.0
17                 0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          2124498.0
18                 0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          3051659.0
19                 0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          1859001.0
20                 0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          8522834.0
21                 0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          7803526.0
22                 0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          4067546.0
23                 0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          9218486.0
24                 0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          1453153.0
25                 0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          7411706.0
26                 0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          9160444.0
27                 0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          6255426.0
28                 0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          6007841.0
29                 0  SST22a,SST22b,    ...          4744588.0
...              ...             ...    ...      ..        ...
133649             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          6487572.0
133650             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          3593805.0
133651             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          9192954.0
133652             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          2394981.0
133653             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          9398971.0
133654             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          5536294.0
133655             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          8759613.0
133656             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          2012212.0
133657             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          7930551.0
133658             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          3407871.0
133659             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          3071541.0
133660             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          1863129.0
133661             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          8439646.0
133662             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          1518097.0
133663             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          7396702.0
133664             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          8470274.0
133665             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          8363095.0
133666             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          1115614.0
133667             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          6317772.0
133668             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          2645613.0
133669             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          6555039.0
133670             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          5274987.0
133671             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          5779789.0
133672             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          6974948.0
133673             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          6370779.0
133674             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          4164305.0
133675             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          7280203.0
133676             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          1235752.0
133677             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          1436891.0
133678             3   SST22b,SST07,    ...          3115825.0
[133679 rows x 16 columns]
```

As you can see, the amount of rows and columns is the same.
The columns are also exactly the same between the two `result`s.
However, when you check the `AMOUNT` column, you see that, for example in the last rows, the `result` from the NEW environment has the values combined (last row swapped for the previous row, for example).

Any ideas why is this happening?

**PS:** Unfortunately, I can not provide a DataFrame which you can load since the DataFrame I'm using has lots of data in it. I'm more of looking to a theoretical answer on what changed between the above mentioned versions of pandas and/or which argument to use in the NEW environment to have the exact same result as in the OLD environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, your data is not sorted and seems like in those versions , pandas returns data in different order.
from Pandas documentations :

> sort in group by just sort the group keys and this does **not** influence the order of observations within each group.

you can sort your data by `.sort_values()` after group by , see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) for more detail

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. Is there any option/argument to pass to make it sort the result in the same way as in the OLD environment?

Comment: @neisor use `sort_values()` on both old and new

Comment: Thank you. That indeed was the issue.